# Firefox audio tag doubles length of OGG Vorbis

Tags: firefox, audio, ffmpeg

So, here I have a demo file from my website

http://members.shaw.ca/darolynk/breakup/html5game/snd_music.ogg

I am running off of Firefox Beta 30.0 and this issue does not persist in Google Chrome. In Firefox, when I play the file back, the length is displayed at around twice of its actual length as 32:13 when it is only 12:52 in length. Even worse, the audio stutters, playing one second of noise, one second of silence. This issue is not persistent in Chrome nor Opera. It is not a streaming issue (the song is streamed by the time it is played back in fact).

I am wondering if this is an issue with the codec or with Firefox's intrepretation of the codec, but more importantly, I want to know how to fix it. Some information about the file: the file is in OGG Vorbis format, 44100 Hz, 32 kbps Mono (yes, I am running out of storage space). It was encoded with SUPER, which in turn uses FFMpeg and MEncoder as necessary.

This does not apply to all files of this format, making the issue even stranger. Are OGG Vorbis files over a certain length not allowed or interpreted differently by Firefox? This must be the case for someone else and not just me...

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Firefox, it's an issue with your file.  Also, I've reproduced the issue in VLC... that'd a bad sign as VLC can usually play any corrupt file you throw at it but I wouldn't be surprised if Firefox used the same libvorbis or whatever for the codec.

Some observations:

- What we have here is sort of a codec issue.  However, the audio being played back is listenable, sort of, meaning it's likely just an issue with some flags.
- The sample rate is correct as all the pitches sound correct.
- The gaps in the audio are at regular intervals, so it isn't likely you have a plainly corrupt file.
- The time on/off in audio is exactly the same length.
- Your file is in mono.

It seems to me like the decoder is looking for stereo interleaved channels, but your file is in mono so it cannot decode the bitstream properly.  VLC tells me the audio is in mono, but if I remember correctly, Ogg and Vorbis can disagree which might be happening here.

I would recommend simply using FFmpeg to do the encoding.  If you still have the problem, at least then we know what version of FFmpeg you have and what the command line was.

Comment: I solved the problem simply by using a different encoder (DVDVideoSoft's to be exact) and now it plays perfectly fine in all browsers. SUPER uses FFMpeg and MEncoder to convert the file so your suggestion to use FFMpeg wouldn't work as far as I know. Anyways it must've been an issue with the file but it is fixed now. Thank you

Comment: @tomysshadow I use FFmpeg every day to convert to Ogg.  I assure you it works fine, but there are 1,001 ways to build FFmpeg.  The specific build with your copy of SUPER might be fubar.  In any case, glad to hear you got it working.